# Don't change the position of the checkbox if you choose "Answer your own question"

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface

If you choose "Answer your own question", the position of the checkbox will be changed. It is not the best user experience.

It would be better from the UX side, if you don't change the checkbox position after a click.

> [image]

Comment: You paid attentions to details. +1